# force www rewrite if wordpress put in a folder

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, mod-rewrite

My wordspress site is installed in myfolder and it auto create the code in htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now I would like to force www to all my links and find this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I put them together it won't work.. Can anyone help me?

Thank you~~~

Answer (score 1):

Place this **above** the # BEGIN WordPress line.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. But seems not working. https://example.com/myfolder will become https://www.example.com/

Comment: The %1 and $1 are variables that preserve /myfolder. Did you try checking the actual HTTP headers with a tool like Webconfs? If you are just trying in your web browser you may be cached, making it look like the changes didn't work when they actually did. Or, your host may have a server-side cache that needs to be cleared.